# HDFS backup using oozie on secure cluster to normal cluster

Tags: security, hdfs, kerberos, oozie

Properties need to be ensured in oozie-site.xml file for oozie backup between the secured cluster to normal cluster..? is there any specific argument need to  passed between oozie command,for oozie backup..?

could you please suggest your ideas and solutions back..?!

Comment: I am not able to understand what you need, Can you please try to rephrase it?

Comment: @YoungHobbit , actually my question is How to schedule  a distcp job on oozie from secured cluster to unsecured  cluster.? so please suggest me what are the properties to be ensured ,to run oozie jobs from secure to normal cluster..?

Comment: @YoungHobbit , actually my question is How to schedule  a distcp job on oozie from secured cluster to unsecured  cluster.? so please suggest me what are the properties to be ensured ,to run oozie jobs from secure to normal cluster..?I tried hadoop distcp -D ipc-client-fallback-simple auth=true by passing arguments in distcp-workflow,but it does not work.? getting error of simple-auth failed